# UITableView disable rowEditActionForRowAtIndexPath for certain rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to implement the "swipe to edit" function for certain rows. If all conditions are fulfilled, the swipe function should be enabled. If not, the row should remain static without any action rowEditAction assigned.

My code looks something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
    var noAction = UITableViewRowAction()

    var logoutAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Log Out ") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            //do stuff when button pressed
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1){
            //do stuff when button pressed
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 0 && conditionsFulfilled()){
        return [logoutAction]
    } else if(indexPath.row == 1 && conditionsFulfilled()){
        return [logoutAction]
    }
    return [noAction]
}
```

This code does not disable the edit function, it just shows an empty `UITableViewRowAction` for rows that should not view the `logoutAction`. How do I get this done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITableViewDataSource` has a method entitled [`canEditRowAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:) that according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:):

> The method permits the data source to exclude individual rows from being treated as editable. Editable rows display the insertion or deletion control in their cells. If this method is not implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable...

So you can do something like this for example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    // in this case I only allow edit from the third cell hereinafter.
    return indexPath.row > 3 ? true : false
}
```

I hope this help you.